# Combining sheets "1" thru "31" into "ALL" sheet in same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a workbook set up to open multiple txt files in excel, filter all the data and import only what i need from it. Each import goes into a different excel sheet "1", "2", "3", .... through "31" (Days).

All sheets have the same number of columns but different number of rows. What i need to do is combine all sheets into the "ALL" sheet within this same workbook.

Help?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Works like a charm. My very first sheet is called "ALL", second sheet is called Setup where i check my date ranges for the files im importing to the rest of the sheets in days which is sheet named "1" through "31". With this macro the 3rd sheet (being sheet "1") is when it starts to combine unti lthe last sheet in the workbook. It copies everything but the first row which has the column headings.

```
Dim J As Integer

On Error Resume Next

For J = 3 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1000000").End(xlUp)(2)

Next

Sheets("ALL").Select
```